# Trying to install MobX but getting decorators error when start up the server

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

When I install Mobx and Mobx react I am getting the following error.

```
./src/index.js
Error: The 'decorators' plugin requires a 'decoratorsBeforeExport' option, 
whose value must be a boolean. If you are migrating from Babylon/Babel 6 or 
want to use the old decorators proposal, you should use the 'decorators-legacy' 
plugin instead of 'decorators'.
```

Now I have ejected the dependencies and installed the decorators-legacy as a plugin.  This is what I have in my package.json file

```
"babel": {
"plugins": [
  "transform-decorators-legacy"
 ],
 "presets": [
  "react-app"
  ]
},
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.1.2",
"babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.5"
}
```

Any help would be appreciated as this has been driving my crazy for the last few days.

Comment: Have you tried making your config look like [the config in this issue](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/issues/1352)?

Comment: Where is the babelrc file?

Comment: At the very top in the issue.

Comment: now I am getting the following  error `./src/index.js
SyntaxError: /Users/briankaty1/Desktop/mobx/mobx2/bird-cage/src/index.js: Unexpected token (7:16)

   5 | import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
   6 | 
>  7 | ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));`

Answer (score 0):

As Tholle wrote the link was very helpful.  My config in my package.json.

```
"babel": {
"presets": ["@babel/preset-env","react-app"],

"plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }],
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true }]
  ]
},
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.1.2",
"babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.5"
}
```